# Seal the End of a Gutter

Tags: gutters

The gutter on the outside of my house I purchased needs a end cap replaced.  However it's more of a square than any of the gutter caps at local shops.  It seems like a strong type of tape that was used before.  Any ideas what I could use? I'm not home at the moment but I think if I remember correctly the size was 6" wide by 5" high.

Comment: Are you asking how to fit a cap, or how to seal the cap to the channel?

Comment: +isherwood really what is it they used that isn't plastic that is more like tape?  I can't find a cap that is that size?

Comment: @RichardW11 what is the gutter made out of?